# Apache Nifi windows unable to load NAR library bundles

Tags: windows, installation, apache-nifi

I'm only attempting to launch the Nifi UI as a local instance to start playing with it. I've unzipped the package and made sure to set the JAVA_HOME variable to my Java 1.8. When I try to bin/run-nifi, in my nifi-app log, the error message is:

```
2018-05-03 15:03:50,585 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Launching NiFi...
    2018-05-03 15:03:52,330 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be 'Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties'
    2018-05-03 15:03:52,363 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 146 properties from Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties
    2018-05-03 15:03:52,423 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Loaded 146 properties
    2018-05-03 15:03:52,779 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 64802
    2018-05-03 15:03:53,071 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
    2018-05-03 15:03:53,181 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker Unable to load NAR library bundles due to java.io.IOException: Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework directory does not have read/write privilege Will proceed without loading any further Nar bundles
    2018-05-03 15:03:53,242 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.io.IOException: Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework could not be created
    java.io.IOException: Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework could not be created
        at org.apache.nifi.util.FileUtils.ensureDirectoryExistAndCanReadAndWrite(FileUtils.java:48)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders.load(NarClassLoaders.java:155)
        at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders.init(NarClassLoaders.java:131)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:133)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292)
    2018-05-03 15:03:53,383 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
    2018-05-03 15:03:53,387 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

I've followed the installation instructions and haven't been able to trouble shoot. How do I load  these NAR files upon running Nifi?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the underlying error in your output is `java.io.IOException: Z:\DoE\LOCAL-~1\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework could not be created`.

NiFi requires file permissions to create and write several directories, there is a list in the [NiFi Admin Guide: How to install and start NiFi](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#how-to-install-and-start-nifi).  NiFi does this to unpack the NAR files, write logs, and for various data repositories that comprise your data flow.

You have a few options:

- Modify the permissions of the directory to allow NiFi read/write access.  This can be done for each individual child directory.
- Copy the entire NiFi distribution to a read/write location and run it from there.
- Edit the `conf/nifi-properties` file to change the locations of these directories to read/write locations. See [NiFi Admin Guide: System Properties](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_properties) for help on the properties.
- Symlinks are a great solution for systems that support symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

- Run NiFi with administrator privilege (not a good practice) by going to `~\<NIFI_INSTALLATION_DIR>\bin` and right click `run-nifi.bat`. Click `Run as Administrator`
- Move NiFi directory to a location where the logged in user has full access to. Ex: `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\Documents\`. Now try to execute `bin\run-nifi.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the resolution that James proposed. I had to do the below 3-step process.

My scenario: I'm using docker containers and had the same problem. Even changing the user of my container to root didn't work. So, I did the following:

`1 - Download Minifi https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/download.html`

`2 - Untar and execute the Minifi agent on my own laptop (I'm using MAC) so that the necessary folders and files will be created.`

`3 - Tar it up again and add to the DockerFile of my container creation`

Done! Everything worked fine after that.